# Formspree: Ajax submit not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using formspree for a one-field form on my page. To avoid redirecting my users to the default thank you page, I'm trying to use ajax to submit the form and display success/error messages.

However, my code isn't working. As far as I can tell, the messages don't appear. I think it has something to do with the messages wanting to display within my button, and my button being an input field..

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8gL30b4/), and here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="contactFormWrapper">
<form id="contact-form"      action="http://formspree.io/myemail@gmail.com" method="POST">
<input type="message" name="name" value placeholder="Chanel Boy.." class="design--form">
<input id="send-button" type="submit"  class="btn--main"  style="width:auto" value="SUBMIT">

</form></div>
```

JS:

```
var contactForm = document.querySelector('#contact-form'),
inputName = contactForm.querySelector('[name="name"]'),
sendButton = contactForm.querySelector('#send-button');

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form to do the post.

  sendButton.innerHTML = 'Sending..';

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '//formspree.io/myemail@gmail.com', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

  xhr.send(
    "name=" + inputName.value;

  xhr.onloadend = function (res) {
    if (res.target.status === 200){
      sendButton.innerHTML = 'Message sent!';
    }
    else {
      sendButton.innerHTML = 'Error!';
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Too many syntax issues. <input name="name"> element missing attribute value="something". xhr.onloadend should be outside xhr.send.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few typos and a misunderstanding on how input values work. Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8gL30b4/2/).

The 2 main issues I saw, were:

1. The `xhr.send` did not have a close parenthesis
2. You can't change the text of an input (`<input type="submit>`) using `innerHTML`, you need to change the `value`: `sendButton.value = 'Sending...';`

This absolutely worked for me when I put my email address in instead of yours. I got the confirmation email from formspree and then was able to submit through the fiddle to myself.