# Formspree contact form using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jekyll, contact-form

I am using formspree to send data to my email. The code looks like this.

 HTML:

```
    <form id="contact-form" >
  <div class="form-stacked" >
              <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                <input type="text"  class="field-light"  id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
              <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="field-light"  id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
                <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                <textarea id="inputMessage" class="field-light"  rows="5" placeholder="Leave a Message" name="message" ></textarea>
        <button class="field-light center" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

and javascript code as :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// $('#h2').hide();
$('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    var name = $('#inputName')
    var email = $('#inputEmail')
    var message = $('#inputMessage')

    if(name.val() == "" || email.val() == "" || message.val() == "") {
      $("#fail").show().delay(3000).hide(0);
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '//formspree.io/mymail@gmail.com',
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
        datatype: 'json'
      });
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).get(0).reset();
      $('#success').show().delay(3000).hide(0);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The code looks  fine but I don't receive any of the emails on submission of the form(I tested it localhost as well on web server). I have checked the [unblock](https://formspree.io/unblock/your@email.com) feature on formspree site and it seems my email is not blocked. I have read [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693539/formspree-ajax-submit-not-working) answer and it works fine but I want to fix this code.

Comment: Does it work without javascript? By setting the action of the form to: //formspree.io/mymail@gmail.com?

Comment: @JoostS yes it does work if we set post directly but the problem is it reveals the email on the address bar.

Comment: Know that javascript can be read by bots too.

Comment: @JoostS i didnt know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formspree has a Gold account. That will hide the email address. If you use another service, like hosting on CloudCannon or a form through the formsubmit.io or formbucket service, your email address will also be truly hidden. Then you can use a simple post in the action of the form.

**UPDATE: Currently (May 2020) the free plan hides your email address too (registration required).**

Comment: I will try formsubmit.io let me see if that works the same way

Comment: Formsubmit.io is working fine! As well I won't need extra javascript code. Thanks man! For those who need help [here](https://formsubmit.io/examples/) .

Comment: Formspree allows ajax today on the free plan that hides the email address.

Comment: formsubmit.co is also helpful in such a scenario

Answer (score 1):

Today Formspree allows AJAX on the free plan and provides a form ID url so you don't need to expose your email address in the `action` endpoint.